# Is there any limit for Employer contributions in the Health Care Plan?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, hsa

the contributions of the  employer for the Health care plan is 100% or it is combination of both the employee and employer. what is the percentage? and the contributions of the employee is taxable or free.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing and understanding your question.  Could you edit your question and explain further exactly what you are asking?

Comment: will employer contribute 100% or  the employee also contribute along with the empolyer? what is the % of the contributions of both employee and employer for the Health Care Plan.

Comment: "will" or "can/must"?  Will seems up to the employer.

Comment: forgive for my bad english it is not "will"

Answer (score 1):

Typically an employee will be required to contribute to some portion of the premium to be enrolled in an employer plan.  100% payment from the employer is becoming increasingly rare.  In some segments of the insurance world, the carriers will impose a 50% requirement on the employer, meaning the employer must contribute at least 50% to the employee's premium amount.

The ACA sets out a penalty if an employee's contribution is not considered to be "affordable."  For penalty avoidance purposes, "affordable" means 9.5% of the employee's earnings from that employer.  So if you make $60,000 per year, that's $5,000 per month, your contribution can be no more than $475 per month or your employer could face a penalty.

Typically, employee benefits plans are run as an IRS Section 125 Cafeteria Plan which gives employees the ability to allow a pre-tax payroll deduction for their contribution to their benefits.  Generally, employee contributions are tax-free.

Comment: what is employer penality?

Comment: The affordable care act outlines a penalty if an employer doesn't offer "affordable" "minimum-essential" coverage to all (95%) of it's "full-time" employees.  The penalty is only imposed if the company has more than 50 full time employees.  If no plan is offered the penalty is $2,160 per full time employee, if a plan is offered but is not affordable or not minimum-essential coverage, the penalty is $3,240 for every employee that receives a tax subsidiarity at an insurance exchange.  The penalties are prorated by month.